# Find a string in a filename with a constant and a regular expression in the middle and replace it

Tags: bash, mv

I feel like this is a lame question, but after a lot of attempts, I'm stuck. I have a large number of files like this:

```
S2EC1_DKDL220005480-2a-AK13554-7UDI265_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_1.fq.gz
S2EC1_DKDL220005480-2a-AK13554-7UDI265_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_2.fq.gz
S2EC2_DKDL220005480-2a-5UDI249-7UDI265_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_1.fq.gz
S2EC2_DKDL220005480-2a-5UDI249-7UDI265_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_2.fq.gz
S2EC11_DKDL220005480-2a-5UDI251-5UDI1063_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_1.fq.gz
S2EC11_DKDL220005480-2a-5UDI251-5UDI1063_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_2.fq.gz
```

and I'm trying to get them renamed to look like this:

```
S2EC1_R1.fastq.gz
S2EC1_R2.fastq.gz
S2EC2_R1.fastq.gz
S2EC2_R2.fastq.gz
S2EC11_R1.fastq.gz
S2EC11_R2.fastq.gz
```

The filenames are variable length. There is a bit that is identical in every filename `DKDL220005480-2a-` and `_HHJ2MCCX2_L8` but it's separated by a bit in the middle that is variable in terms of composition and length.

From my bash shell I can make some progress in a kind of a step-wise fashion by doing this to get rid of the constant text:

```
for x in *; do mv $x ${x/DKDL220005480-2a-/}; done
for x in *; do mv $x ${x/_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_/_R}; done
```

Which yields file names like this:

```
S2EC1_AK13554-7UDI265_R1.fq.gz
S2EC1_AK13554-7UDI265_R2.fq.gz
S2EC2_5UDI249-7UDI265_R1.fq.gz
S2EC2_5UDI249-7UDI265_R2.fq.gz
S2EC11_5UDI251-5UDI1063_R1.fq.gz
S2EC11_5UDI251-5UDI1063_R2.fq.gz
```

But now I'm failing to find and replace the variable parts in the middle. Of course it would also be much more elegant to do it all in one go.

Here is what I consider my most promising code for matching that variable middle bit:

```
for x in *; do mv $x ${x/_(.+)_/}; done
```

But I get this error:

```
mv: 'S2EC1_AK13554-7UDI265_R1.fq.gz' and 'S2EC1_AK13554-7UDI265_R1.fq.gz' are the same file
mv: 'S2EC1_AK13554-7UDI265_R2.fq.gz' and 'S2EC1_AK13554-7UDI265_R2.fq.gz' are the same file
mv: 'S2EC2_5UDI249-7UDI265_R1.fq.gz' and 'S2EC2_5UDI249-7UDI265_R1.fq.gz' are the same file
mv: 'S2EC2_5UDI249-7UDI265_R2.fq.gz' and 'S2EC2_5UDI249-7UDI265_R2.fq.gz' are the same file
mv: 'S2EC11_5UDI251-5UDI1063_R1.fq.gz' and 'S2EC11_5UDI251-5UDI1063_R1.fq.gz' are the same file
mv: 'S2EC11_5UDI251-5UDI1063_R2.fq.gz' and 'S2EC11_5UDI251-5UDI1063_R2.fq.gz' are the same file
```

Not sure if it's something wrong with my regular expression or my mv code (or both or even possibly something else, ha ha).

Thanks

Comment: Why the last `S2EC11_R1.fastq.gz`? Shouldn't it be `S2EC11_R2.fastq.gz`?

Comment: Ah, yes! Copy and paste error. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching and regular expressions are two different things. In pattern matching `*` means *any string*. In regular expressions it means *zero or more of what precedes*. In pattern matching `(.+)` means... the literal `(.+)` string. In regular expressions it represents a capture group with at least one character.

For your simple renaming scheme you can try:

```bash
for f in *.fq.gz; do
  g="${f/_DKDL220005480-2a-*_HHJ2MCCX2_L8_/_R}"
  printf 'mv "%s" "%s"\n' "$f" "${g%.fq.gz}.fastq.gz"
#  mv "$f" "${g%.fq.gz}.fastq.gz"
done
```

Once satisfied with the output uncomment the `mv` line.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful to see that I've fundamentally misunderstood something. So if I interpret correctly then, it's not possible to use a regex in the middle of a pattern matching. I need to do one or the other.

Comment: That's it. Use regular expressions with `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc. or with the `[[ string =~ regex ]]` `bash` operator but not with pattern matching. Note that when the `extglob` `bash` option is enabled (`shopt -s extglob`), several extra pattern matching operators can be used (`?(pattern|pattern|...)` for zero or one occurrence of one of the `pattern`, `*(pattern|pattern|...)`, ...) Still not the full power of regular expressions but a bit better than the plain pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

To use regular expressions in `bash` you need to use `[[ $x =~ regex ]]`, and you can use groups with `$BASH_REMATCH`, so:

```
for x in *; do
    [[ $x =~ ^(S2EC[0-9]+)_.*_([0-9]+).fq.gz$ ]] &&
        mv $x ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_R${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.fastq.gz
done
```